# ternary operators in binding angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an issue and I cant seem to figure it out, basically I'm trying to use a ternary if statement in a `[src]` attribute in angular

```
<img class="author-head" [src]="(asset.fields.authorHeadImage != null || asset.fields.authorHeadImage != undefined ) ? asset.fields.authorHeadImage?.fields?.file.url : ../../../../assets/Images/CustomContent/author.jpg" >
```

basically what Im trying to do here is if `asset.fields.authorHeadImage` is null or `asset.fields.authorHeadImage` is undefined show this predetermined image but if there is an `authorHeadImage` then use that image src..

but I keep getting these massive errors in my console that dont really mean anything?

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

**EDIT**

I switched the operators around and now Im getting this error it says I have an unexpected fullstop at column 136 but there are no rogue fullstops?

```
Parser Error: Unexpected token . at column 136 in [(asset.fields.authorHeadImage != null || asset.fields.authorHeadImage != undefined) ? asset.fields.authorHeadImage?.fields?.file.url : ../../../../assets/Images/CustomContent/drsultan.jpg] in ng:///MainModule/ProgramItemComponent.html@5:37 ("
      <div *ngIf="asset.fields.showAuthorHead === true">
        <img class="author-head" [ERROR ->][src]="(asset.fields.authorHeadImage != null || asset.fields.authorHeadImage != undefined) ? asset.fi"): ng:///MainModule/ProgramItemComponent.html@5:37
Parser Error: Unexpected token . at column 136 in [(asset.fields.authorHeadImage != null || asset.fields.authorHeadImage != undefined) ? asset.fields.authorHeadImage?.fields?.file.url : ../../../../assets/Images/CustomContent/drsultan.jpg] in ng:///MainModule/ProgramItemComponent.html@5:37 ("ile.url : ../../../../assets/Images/CustomContent/drsultan.jpg" >
```

Comment: Do you see any error related to this code. Do you still get errors when you comment out your code?

Comment: @SangramNandkhile see updated question

Comment: You are missing single quotes around image source file. That could be the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following syntaxes should work. The alternate URL is surrounded with single quotes since it is a literal string. In the first syntax, the two NOT operators `!!` make it clear that the value it treated as a boolean in the condition.

```
<img [src]="!!asset.fields.authorHeadImage ? asset.fields.authorHeadImage : '../../../../assets/Images/CustomContent/author.jpg'" ... >
<img [src]="asset.fields.authorHeadImage || '../../../../assets/Images/CustomContent/author.jpg'" ... >
```

Comment: is it true that the value of src property will evaluate in every change detection cycle is ite the same as function call `[src]="getUrl()"`

Comment: @malbarmawi - As far as I know, every binding expression is evaluated on change detection. The expression in the answer above will be evluated every time, yes, as would be a method call or a simple property. By the way, calling a method is not bad, as long as it executes quickly (see [these guidelines](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#expression-guidelines)).

Comment: What if i have three possibilities, how can i add a second condition to the ternary operator?

Comment: @lautarojgarcia177 - You could try something like `[src]="cond1 ? val1 : (cond2 ? val2 : val3)"`.

Answer (score 3):

Haven't tested but something like this should be a way to go. Keeps your html cleaner.

```
 <img class="author-head" [src]="asset.fields.authorHeadImage != null  ? asset.fields.authorHeadImage : myImgUrl" >
```

> .ts file

```
export class App{
   myImgUrl: string='../../../../assets/Images/CustomContent/author.jpg';
}
```